# MAC The VPN client agent was unable to create the client DNS plugin manager

Tags: macos, mac, cisco-anyconnect, cisco-webex

I am getting errors

> The VPN client agent was unable to create the client DNS plugin
> manager.

after every 10 seconds when un-installed `Cisco AnyConnect` software from the finder in mac.

how to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 6):

In mac, I debug and figured out there were some undeleted files of cisco. deleting that fixed the issue.

Command:-

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/cisco
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Now I get error: Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client.app cannot be opened because of a problem. Check with the developer to make sure Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client.app works with this version of macOS. You may need to reinstall the application. Be sure to install any available updates for the application and macOS.

Click Report to see more detailed information and send a report to Apple.

Comment: i guess your use case is different from us in my case i already uninstalled the cisco software and just wanted to get rid of this annoying error msj so the above command helped me doing that.
can you tell me you want the software to work on your local that is why you tried above command right..?

Comment: sure, i was using anyconnect and removed original installation following some odd tutorial clearing free space on mac os :D since then it didn't work, so i reinstalled from my company side version `anyconnect-macos-4.9.00086-core-vpn-webdeploy-k9` nothing since helped. i followed  online tutorials to uninstall and tried re-install with no progress. now if i run installed app my finder is unusable as it keep throwing error " The VPN client agent was unable to create the client DNS plugin manager.". i will talk to tech support internally. so will see.

Comment: Thanks @officialrahulmandal! this error was ruining my life and your fix worked! Thanks again!

Comment: heheh, realy good advice - just force remove the cisco directory in your system :) really good advice!

Answer (score 1):

The answer from officialrahulmandal and command worked to resolve for me too. For those of you who need a little more help:

1. Open the Terminal.app using the spyglass search at top right corner of your mac screen.
2. Once open, copy/paste his command line as shown
3. Hit enter